# Deck of Cards Probability Dividing by n!

Tags: combinatorics

1) Assume we have a standard poker deck of 52 cards, 13 each with 4 suits. What is the probability of picking 3 same numbered cards and 2 same numbered cards (A triple and a pair so AAABB).

Solution: `(13C1)(4C3)(12C1)(4C2)/(52C5)`

2) Let's say you have a deck of cards with **only** a 10, Jack, Queen, King and Ace of which the cards only belong to the suits of Heart and Diamonds. So there are 10 cards in total. Of the 10 cards you deal yourself a hand of 5 random cards. What is the probability of drawing no pairs??

You select one of the 5 pairs (5C1) and of that 2 pair you select one random car (2C1)
Now you have 4 remaining pairs. You pick a pair (4C1) and from that pair you select a card (2C1)
...
So you have

```
(5C1)(2C1)(4C1)(2C1)(3C1)(2C1)(2C1)(2C1)(1C1)(2C1)=5!*2^5
```

we divide by `5!` because of duplicates (order does not matter) then 
divide by the total number of possible combinations `(10C5)`
Ans:

```
2^5/(10C5)
```

Now this is my question: why is it in the first problem we did not divide by n! and in the second problem we did?? You divide by n! when order doesn't matter. But why did we not take that into account in the first problem but did do so in the second?

Comment: Try using `\binom{n}{k}` for binomial coefficients ;)

Comment: Thanks Jon will use from now on. Wasn't sure what the function was. Will correct the typo pointed out by Andre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, it is probably a typo, but the answer is not correct.

There are $\binom{13}{1}$ ways to choose the "number" you will have $3$ of. The rest is as you have it. The total number of "full house" hands is
$$\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{2}.$$

I would do the second question differently, though with the same final answer. There is only one way, or if you prefer $\binom{5}{5}$ ways, to select the *kinds* of cards in your hand. Now for each kind, you have $2$ choices of actual card, for a total of $2^5$. Then we divide by $\dbinom{10}{5}$.

Your way is fine too. You imagined picking the cards *in order*, one at a time, and divided by $5!$ to compensate for the multiple counting. Instead, for the denominator you could also consider ordered choices of $5$ cars, of which there are $(10)(9)(8)(7)(6)$.

The reason we did not have to consider order in the first problem is that for a full house, you **choose** what kind you will have $3$ of, and what kind you will have $2$ of. If we were counting $2$ pair hands (so $2$ pairs and an odd card), saying we can choose the "first" (??) kind in $\binom{13}{1}$ ways and the second in $\binom{12}{1}$ ways would give a double-counting error: we then have to divide by $2!$. Or alternately one can say we can choose the $2$ kinds that we have a pair in in $\binom{13}{2}$ ways.

Comment: Andre thank you very much for your response on this question. I am still trying to wrap my head about the last paragraph you wrote. So in the first problem, the full house (triple & pair), you said "in the first problem is that for a full house, you choose what kind you will have 3 of, and what kind you will have 2 of" but how does this differ from the second problem where I chose a pair from the 5 pairs and then selecting one from that pair?

Comment: For the example you gave (2 pairs and an odd card) I would select a card from the 13 (Ace,1,2,...10,J,Q,K) availiable (13C1) and from that card I have 4 suits availiable (eg, face card with a 10 on it I have 10_D,10_S,10_C,10_H) and I would pull 2 of them. Similarly for the second pair 12 cards to choose from and 4 of each. So (12C1)(4C2). For the last remaining card I would pick another from the 11 remaining and 1 from the 4, so (11C1)(4C1). But in this case I don't need to consider order, am I right. Why?

Comment: For the odd card, I would write simply $\binom{44}{1}$ or just $44$. I dealt with the two pair hand in my answer, and said essentially that $\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{44}{1}$ is **wrong.** We have to divide by $2!$ because there is no "first" kind that we have $2$ of, and second kind. We would be counting $2$ Jacks and $2$ $7$'s, but also counting $2$ $7$'s and $2$ Jacks. The reason we don't have to worry in the full house case is that $3$ Jacks and $2$ $7$'s is a different hand than $3$ $7$'s and $2$ Jacks, so we are not double-counting.

Comment: Andrea. I think I am beginning to follow you -- but what do you mean exactly by when you say "We have to divide by 2! because there is no "first" kind that we have 2 of, and second kind". But when we are picking the first card from A,2,3,..,J,Q,K isn't that a "kind" or category?

Comment: 1) So are you saying because I have (nCx)(mCx) where x is some integer  I am double counting? Where opposed to (nCx)(nCy) where x doesn't equal y, then I am not double counting? 2) When we are double counting how do you know by what number factorial to divide by? In your example (2 pairs, odd card) you divided by 2!. In my 2nd example it was by 5!. Is there a formulaic way when looking at (aCb)(jCk)...(pCq) to know by what n! factorial to divide by?

Comment: I really appreciate all your help Andrea. I know it must feel like your trying to teach a monkey how to count. I can't thank you enough for your patience.

Comment: You are welcome. It takes a little while for these things to "click" but once they do it remains clear forever.

Comment: 1) So Andrea are you saying because I have (nCx)(mCx) where x is some integer I am double counting? Where opposed to (nCx)(nCy) where x doesn't equal y, then I am not double counting?        2) When we are double counting how do you know by what number factorial to divide by? In your example (2 pairs, odd card) you divided by 2!. In my 2nd example it was by 5!. Is there a formulaic way when looking at (aCb)(jCk)...(pCq) to know by what n! factorial to divide by?

Comment: I don't think in terms of the *shape* of the formula. Specifically, what I wrote was that $\binom{13}{1}\binom{12}{1}$ counted among others $2$ Jacks and $2$ $7$'s, and counted $2$ $7$'s and $2$ Jacks as different. But they give the same hand. Since in the denominator we are counting hands, the probability we compute is twice the correct one. If poker was played with $6$ cards, then $\binom{13}{1}\binom{12}{1}\binom{11}{1}\binom{4}{2}^3$ would overcount the "three pairs" hands by a factor of $3!$.

Comment: I see. So in the (2 pair, 1 odd example). \binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{2}

Comment: Two pair and additional "different" card: $\frac{1}{2!}\binom{13}{1}\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{2}^2\binom{44}{1}$ or alternately $\binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{2}^2\binom{44}{1}$.

Comment: Sorry. Got locked out of editing mode while I was typing. I see. So in the (2 pair, 1 odd example). You said in the first pair what if I had picked 2 Jacks and in the second pair picked 2 7's. Then you said, "well I could also techinically pick 2 7's in the first pair and 2 J's in the second case". Hence I have duplicates. But isn't this a product of a the fact we have (nCx)(mCx)? But why didn't you divide by 4! since you technically have 4 cards.

Comment: Because $\binom{13}{1}\binom{12}{1}$ overcounts the *kinds* only. Anyway, you should be using $\binom{13}{2}$, which does not overcount anything.